# File Locked Updated Sharepoint Document

Tags: c#, file, events, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to do some changes to the properties of the documents that users edit in a Sharepoint 2010 Document Library progammatically using an Event Handler. At the moment, I'm trying with the event `ItemCheckedIn`. The problem comes when I execute the following instruction:

```
item.File.Update();
```

It gives me an exception saying that the document is locked by user XXX.

Am I updating the properties in the wrong event? How can I avoid this exception?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
item.SystemUpdate()
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office Word is issuing a lock request on documents by default and it is different than 'Checked Out' state.
'Lock' is release only after document is closed by Word. While 'Check Out' can be performed via Word or web interface and it would remain such until explicitly requested to 'Check In'.

As previous comment suggest, the best remedy is to to use in your code:
`item.SystemUpdate(false)` as that would not obey to 'Lock' state and save any changes done via Event handler code.